# HTML5 Regular expression for pattern from 0 to 120 with interval of 5 and white space allowed?

Tags: regex, html

I'm trying to get Regex fro HTML5 pattern attribute. My field should accept values from 0 to 120. There is interval of 5, so any value like 0,5,10,15,... 105,110,115,120 or they can enter or leave it blank. I'm wondering if there is a way to set the increment in REGEX? Here is my example:

```
<input type="text" name="fld1" id="fld1" value="" size="2" maxlength="3" pattern="[0-9]|[0-2]{1,3}" title="Integers from 0 to 120 with increment of 5 or leave it empty." />
```

Comment: You can't set the increment in regex but you can by setting `step` to `"5"` in a number input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="120" step="5">
```

Comment: Better than regex.

Comment: The best answer I'd say.  Even better than .. sniff... cry.. my regex

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type='text' pattern='^(((\d|1[0-1])?(0|5)|120)|)$' />
```

REGEX isn't designed for numerical validation, but as you can see it can occasionally be possible with carefully-designed patterns.

That pattern says the beginning should be either any number (for numbers between 11 and 99) or 1 + either 1 or 0 (for numbers between 100-119), or neither. Most important, the final - or only - number should be a 0 or a 5.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lge4m44h/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Use this Pattern `\b([05]|\d[05]|1[01][05]|120)\b` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OLyRFB/1)

```
\b          # <word boundary>
(           # Capturing Group (1)
  [05]      # Character in [05] Character Class
  |         # OR
  \d        # <digit 0-9>
  [05]      # Character in [05] Character Class
  |         # OR
  1         # "1"
  [01]      # Character in [01] Character Class
  [05]      # Character in [05] Character Class
  |         # OR
  120       # "120"
)           # End of Capturing Group (1)
\b          # <word boundary>
```

Answer (score 0):

No increments that I am aware of.  You can sort of make your own with a regex though:

```
^([05]|[1-9][05]|1[0-1][05]|120)$
```

Pretty much just having it say, you can have:

1. one number, 0 or 5
2. two numbers, first can be any non 0, then the second must be a 0 or 5
3. three numbers, first must be a 1, second 0 through 2, 3rd a 0 or a 5

The entire line must be like that.  It can be adjust to allow leading or trailing white space if that is required.  There will be several ways to write a regex like this, it just comes down to readability in my opinion. Good luck!

Comment: your pattern matches `125`